# automatic comma in aligned inside tabular

Tags: tables, align

I want to type two independent equations, one below another, and the second one having an aligned iff chain. I've coded the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage{commath} 

\begin{document}

\def\,{{,}}

\begin{tabular}{l}
    $1+q_{12}+6=15  \iff q_{12} = 8$; \\
    $\begin{aligned}
            q_{12} + q_{22} + 9= 15 & \iff 8+q_{22} + 9= 15\\
            & \iff q_{22} = -2
    \end{aligned}$
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The result is what I wanted, except for a comma that was automatically inserted in the middle of the equations.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) If the only contents of that `tabular` is maths, consider using `array` instead.

Comment: I have no such comma inserted. On the other hand, why don't you use a plain  `align*` for this group of equations?

Comment: please always post a complete small document that shows the problem. The code that you posted does not produce a comma.  (`tabular` is  not the right environment for a math display, but that would not produce the comma)

Comment: After isolating some parts of the code, I've found out that a \def produced the comma I was talking about. I've updated my question to add a small document. Anyway, thanks for the hints on not using tabular.

Answer (score 2):

Your question isn't clear nothing in the code you posted makes a comma (or did you mean the semicolon `;` ?)

A `tabular` is not intended for making math displays, and as you had it, the first row was in inline math style and the later rows in display math.

I think that your intended layout using `aligned` is as shown below using `gather*` but perhaps the second version using `align*` looks more natural.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

gather
\begin{gather*}
    1+q_{12}+6=15  \iff q_{12} = 8 \\
    \begin{aligned}
            q_{12} + q_{22} + 9= 15 & \iff 8+q_{22} + 9= 15\\
            & \iff q_{22} = -2
    \end{aligned}
\end{gather*}

align
\begin{align*}
    1+q_{12}+6=15  &\iff q_{12} = 8 \\
            q_{12} + q_{22} + 9= 15 & \iff 8+q_{22} + 9= 15\\
            & \iff q_{22} = -2
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about `gather`. The equations are aligned left on my document, so I think that the option with `gather` is more suitable.